# Connecting nodes under certain conditions and trying to find the correct sequence on OEIS to describe the situation.

Tags: graph-theory

I would like to construct graphs under the following conditions:

- No loops
- Maximum of one edge between any nodes
- Connected
- No intersection between the edges may occur on a plane.

Now, a similar problem minus the condition of non-intersection on the plane results in the Catalan numbers, [A000108](http://oeis.org/A000108). However, I wish to find the sequence that expresses $a_n$ as the number of unique graphs as above with n nodes. So far I have $1,1,2,5,13$ [sic]. For these I am sure, but it is daunting to try and draw out all possible graphs of $6$ without me missing any, and I have not yet worked out an algorithm to generate them.

Also, I am sorry if I am not using correct terminology, I have searched for the notation to describe these nodes but I am feeling slightly overwhelmed by [Wikipedia's glossary](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossary_of_graph_theory). If someone could express my "rules" with the correct jargon that would make me very happy.

Finally, I have a suspicion that [A001519](http://oeis.org/A001519) is the answer I am searching for. If it is indeed the correct solution, then why is it referring to trees when I allow cycles, is it merely coincidence?

Comment: It looks to me like you are looking for _connected planar simple graphs_.

Comment: You're right, sorry for such a trivial error which broadcasts my ignorance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You appear to be trying to count [connected simple planar graphs](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PlanarConnectedGraph.html), but if so, you’re missing one on four nodes and seven on five nodes: this is [OEIS A003094](http://oeis.org/A003094), and the six of them on four nodes are pictured at the first link.

Comment: Oh, I'm such an idiot I forgot the square for four nodes and after that all variations thereof were missed. Yes this is exactly right, thanks!

Comment: @nathan: You’re welcome!